# CakePHP naming convention

Tags: cakephp

I have the following tables:

- administrators
- properties
- administrators_properties

Controller files are titled:

- administrators_controller.php
- properties_controller.php
- administrators_properties_controller.php

Model files are titled:

- administrator.php
- property.php
- administrators_property.php

I'm having trouble understanding the singular/plural naming convention for the joined model name. (Or could the problem be with the controller?  Maybe administrator_properties_controller.php?)

Any obvious issue come to mind?

Comment: Generally you don't need to create a model for the join table. Unless there is extra data in the join CakePHP will handle it automagically. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have troubles understanding how to pluralize or singularize words, use inflector:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html

If you are using CakePHP 2.X, your naming is wrong. You should read about CakePHP naming conventions on the cookbook:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

**Tables:**

> Table names corresponding to CakePHP models are plural and underscored.

**Join tables:**

> Join tables, used in hasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM) relationships between models should be named after the model tables they will join in alphabetical order (apples_zebras rather than zebras_apples).

**Controllers:**

> Controller classnames are plural, CamelCased, and end in Controller. PeopleController and LatestArticlesController are both examples of conventional controller names.

**Models:**

> Model classnames are singular and CamelCased. Person, BigPerson, and ReallyBigPerson are all examples of conventional model names.

In your case your tables are ok. About the rest:

Controllers should be: `AdministratorsController.php`, `PropertiesController.php`, `AdministratorsPropertiesController.php`

Models should be: `Administrator.php`, `Property.php`, `AdministratorsProperty.php`

Comment: Thank you for the links, but I'm not sure this is correct.  The class names within the files are camelcase, but the file names themselves are lowercase with underscores per the documentation.

Comment: CakePHP 2.x has moved to naming the files the same as the class. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#file-and-classname-conventions

Comment: Thanks all, I should have mentioned I was using 1.3.